# if condition, set formula, else allow user input

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[GoogleSheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fYfuP.png)

Is it possible to make the following condition in column H:

```
if B26 == "Asset":
    H26 = SUMIF(B2:B35,"Salary",G2:G35)
else:
    H26 = input(*user input*)
```

I am not sure how to represent the logic for GoogleSheet, so I use python syntax.

I want to automate column `H` according to the category in column `B` to either apply a formula in case the category is `Asset` or values to be manually added for any other category.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Google Sheets a cell must either have a manually entered value or a value generated by a formula, you cannot have both.

However, there is a workaround to this, you can add a hidden column before the interested column and enter the following formula in it:

- If the *locale* is set to a country that uses points as decimal separators:

```
=IF(condition,{"",formula},{"",""})
```

- If the *locale* is set to a country that uses commas as decimal separators:

```
=IF(condition;{""\formula};{""\""})
```

---

For your specific case, you have to add a hidden column before column `H` and use the following formula:

```
=IF(B26="Asset",{"",SUMIF(B2:B35,"Salary",G2:G35)},{"",""})
```